# Issue in React Native Azure AD Authentication with React-native-azure-ad-2

Tags: android, reactjs, azure, react-native, azure-active-directory

I am building mobile application in React Native. Where I have to login with Azure AD using **React-native-azure-ad-2** package. I have registered my application on Azure AD in App Registration by selecting **Public client (mobile & desktop)** option. My users will download this application from Intune Company Portal.

Now I have few questions and facing below issues.

1) What should I write in Rediret URI while app registration?

2) Currently I am writing deep linking path. Is this correct option? {scheme}://{host}

3) If I am passing deep linking path it is redirecting me to the page but it is not calling my login success function.

Answer (score 1):

1. For mobile and desktop applications, Azure uses the redirect URI to return token responses so you just need to enter a value specific to your application (https://myfirstAADApp or https://localhost:44321/).
2. It should be scheme, domain/host, and port/path (if applicable). 
   [image]
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-desktop/
3. Check the troubleshooting steps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-sign-in-other-problem-deeplink

This document should help you get everything set up properly. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-redirect-uris-to-your-application